# 'Bad request' using python-requests-aws

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests

I'm trying to use the [requests-aws](https://github.com/tax/python-requests-aws) package as follows:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from awsauth import S3Auth
```

Then, after defining the `ACCESS_KEY` and `SECRET_KEY` variables together with a `url` which is of the specified format `'http://mybuck.s3.amazonaws.com/file.txt'` (with `mybuck` replaced by an actual bucket), I try to make the `PUT` request:

```
In [8]: r = requests.put(url, data=s, auth=S3Auth(ACCESS_KEY
   ...: , SECRET_KEY))

In [9]: r.ok
Out[9]: False

In [10]: r.reason
Out[10]: 'Bad Request'
```

However, as you can see it is seen as a 'Bad Request' (status code 400). What is going wrong here?

Comment: Why not using boto3 to pull an object? http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get